# Admob & ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, admob

I saw that Admob just released an SDK for Flash Lite (Action Script 2). I'm working on an AS3 
project, and could not find anywhere on the internet an AS3 version of the SDK.

Does anyone have any knowledge of such an SDK for AS3 or using the AS2 SDK in AS3.

Thanks

Can

Answer (score 0):

There is no as3 sdk. Also the as2 sdk does not work in as3. It needs to be rewritten in as3. I am not very talented with as3. Can someone rewrite the AdMobAd.as class to as3?

Comment: Ok I finally got Admob to work in AS3. To do this, I created a simple php on my web server which displays the Admod contents using the Mobile Website solution. Then using the HTMLLoader class in AS3 (Air 1.0) I  display the ad in my App.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the AS2 SDK in an AS2 file that has some methods exposed or reads some URL variables and then try to load that AS2 SWF file into an AS3 container. More info on loading AS2 files in AS3 containers can be found here:

[Load AS2 SWF Into AS3 SWF and pass vars in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481433/load-as2-swf-into-as3-swf-and-pass-vars-in-url)

and here:

http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showpost.php?p=1964550&postcount=249

It's a total pain, but it beats having to write the SDK all over again in AS3.

Answer (score 0):

You can check my test [flash application for android](http://android.jmsliu.com/332/add-admob-in-flash-android-air-application.html). I use the StageWebView with html to load the admob. What u need to do is hosting your html page which embeds the admob ads on your web host, then load the html page in your application by StageWebView.

Comment: Have you had a live app using this method? I'm afraid AdMob might think its click fraud when its not. Have you heard of anyone getting their accounts shut down?