# loading external movie as2 wrapper

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2, localconnection

[Load AS2 SWF Into AS3 SWF and pass vars in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481433/load-as2-swf-into-as3-swf-and-pass-vars-in-url)

I'm trying to load in a as3 file an external as2 swf file (of which I dont have access to fla file). According to the explanation given in the link above, the solution would be to use a as2 wrapper to the original as2 file (and establish a localconnection between the the as3 and as2 files). I've tried to do that, but although the movie seems to load in my as3 file, it doesnt start, doesnt play and gets stuck in the first frame. How do I play the movie (as well as load it)? Thanks for your help.

My as3 file is:

```
import com.gskinner.utils.SWFBridgeAS3;

var loader = new Loader()
loader.load(new URLRequest("as2_test.swf"));

addChild(loader);

var sb1:SWFBridgeAS3 = new SWFBridgeAS3("test",this);
```

my as2 file is:

```
import com.gskinner.utils.SWFBridgeAS2;

var sb1 = new SWFBridgeAS2("test",this);
sb1.addEventListener("connect",this);

var loader:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
loader.addListener(this);

loader.loadClip("digestive.swf", mainLoader_mc);
```

**EDIT:** I keep having this problem. This is what I have so far:

as2 file - as2test.fla (this needs to download another as2 file -digestive.sfw and acts as wrapper to establish connection between the original as2 file and the main as3 file)

```
import com.gskinner.utils.SWFBridgeAS2;

var sb1 = new SWFBridgeAS2("test",this);
sb1.addEventListener("connect",this);

var my_pb:mx.controls.ProgressBar;
my_pb.mode = "manual";

this.createEmptyMovieClip("img_mc22", 999);

var my_mcl:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
var mclListener:Object = new Object();

mclListener.onLoadStart = function(target_mc:MovieClip):Void {
    my_pb.label = "loading: " + target_mc._name;
};

mclListener.onLoadProgress = function(target_mc:MovieClip, numBytesLoaded:Number,    numBytesTotal:Number):Void {
    var pctLoaded:Number = Math.ceil(100 * (numBytesLoaded / numBytesTotal));
    my_pb.setProgress(numBytesLoaded, numBytesTotal);
    trace(pctLoaded);
};

my_mcl.addListener(mclListener);
my_mcl.loadClip("digestive.swf", img_mc22);

stop();
```

as3 file (this plays the as2 wrapper):

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;

function startLoad()
{
    var mLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    var mRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("as2test.swf");
    mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
    mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgressHandler);
    mLoader.load(mRequest);
}

function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event)
{
    addChild(loadEvent.currentTarget.content);
}

function onProgressHandler(mProgress:ProgressEvent)
{
    var percent:Number = mProgress.bytesLoaded/mProgress.bytesTotal;
    trace(percent);
}

startLoad();
stop();
```

In the as2 wrapper file, the original movie plays until a certain frame; in the as3 file, the as2 wrapper file only plays the first frame. What do I have to do?????

Comment: It's a bit tough to troubleshoot. The AS2 file seems incomplete to me (eg. where is mainLoader_mc?). What do you know about 'digestive.swf'? Is it just timeline animation? My best advice would be to create 2 test files so you can get a real handle on how LocalConnection works, cause all Grant (gskinner) has done is make a little wrapper for it to make life easier, which doesn't necessarily make it easier to understand. (Grant is awesome btw.) Tell us more!